# Angular Material - Mat-tabs - How to align a single tab to the right?

Tags: angular-material

Angular Material Tabs - can we align just the "Third" tab to the right?

Here is a stackbliz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3keysh-czzstn?file=app%2Ftab-group-align-example.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3keysh-vflzyz?file=app%2Ftab-group-align-example.html,app%2Ftab-group-align-example.css,app%2Ftab-group-align-example.ts

```css
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header .mat-tab-label:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image]